# how to scan null index in array, and print it with a new value in php?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, variables, conditional-statements

```
<?php

function tambah_penumpang($daftar_penumpang, $penumpang_baru){
    if(empty($namaArray)==true){
        $daftar_penumpang[]=$penumpang_baru;
        return $daftar_penumpang;
    }else{
        for($i=0; $i<count($daftar_penumpang); $i++){
            if($daftar_penumpang[$i]== null){
                $daftar_penumpang[$i]=$penumpang_baru;
                return $daftar_penumpang;
            }else{
                $daftar_penumpang[] = $penumpang_baru;
                return $daftar_penumpang;
            }
        }
    }

}
    $daftar_penumpang =["sandhika",null,"carl","keith"];
    print_r(tambah_penumpang($daftar_penumpang,"anggoro"))."<br>"
?>
```

And this are the result: (i want that anggoro name in null's index)

```
Array ( 
    [0] => sandhika 
    [1] => 
    [2] => carl 
    [3] => keith 
    [4] => anggoro 
)
```

Comment: you mean replace with the same order ?

Comment: yes, replace it to null index by scanning the null index/location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I'm not familiar with your naming convention , i've made a global example using [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) as follows:

```
$daftar_penumpang =["sandhika",null,"carl","keith"];

array_walk($daftar_penumpang, function($v, $k, $replacement) use (&$daftar_penumpang) {
    if ($v == null) {
        $daftar_penumpang[$k] = $replacement;
    }
}, 'anggoro');

print_r($daftar_penumpang);
```

live example: https://3v4l.org/vVnSq

---

for your case :

```
$daftar_penumpang =["sandhika",null,"carl","keith"];

function tambah_penumpang($daftar_penumpang, $penumpang_baru) {
    array_walk($daftar_penumpang, function($v, $k, $replacement) use (&$daftar_penumpang) {
        if ($v == null) {
            $daftar_penumpang[$k] = $replacement;
        }
    }, $penumpang_baru);

    return $daftar_penumpang;
}


print_r(tambah_penumpang($daftar_penumpang, 'anggoro'));
```

this will output:

```
Array ( [0] => sandhika [1] => anggoro [2] => carl [3] => keith )
```

---

### Update

using for loop :

your code issue is that you will never ever get into the for loop because it is in `else` condition , and while the `$namaArray` is alway empty, so you will never go through the loop , so i've removed this check and prepared this looping to show you how to replace null values using for loop

```
function tambah_penumpang($daftar_penumpang, $penumpang_baru)
{
    $tmpArray = [];
    for ($i=0; $i < count($daftar_penumpang); $i++) {
        if ($daftar_penumpang[$i]== null) {
            $tmpArray[$i] = $penumpang_baru;
        } else {
            $tmpArray[] = $daftar_penumpang[$i];
        }
    }
    return $tmpArray;
}

$daftar_penumpang =["sandhika",null,"carl","keith"];
print_r(tambah_penumpang($daftar_penumpang,"anggoro"));
```

Comment: my professor told me to use the UDF function, is that possible i replace ur code into my function body?

Comment: tell him that php provide some new cool features like array_walk

Comment: however, your code return with new value instead of replacement because this peace `if(empty($namaArray)==true)`

Comment: so, my error causes only in this only peace of code if(empty($namaArray)==true) ?? wthh

Comment: how do you send `$namaArray` ??

Comment: it's always empty , so you are always go to the first condition and your code never goes to the else

Comment: I've updated my answer by for loop solution, check it out

Comment: omfg, he really ruined my daytime. can you tell me the workflow process of ur code pleasee?

do u have some skype or any social account, so i could ask with you when i have some problem (if you are not busy)

Comment: you are welcome any time, i think that it will be better to post your question here in Stackoverflow so many people who have the same issue may benefits from the answers;

Answer (score 0):

Try with this function :

```
<?php

function tambah_penumpang($daftar_penumpang, $penumpang_baru){
    $datas = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($daftar_penumpang); $i++) {
        $item = $daftar_penumpang[$i];
        if($item === null) {
            $item = $penumpang_baru;
        }
        $datas[$i] = $item;
    }

    return $datas;
}

$daftar_penumpang =["sandhika",null,"carl","keith"];
print_r(tambah_penumpang($daftar_penumpang,"anggoro"))."<br>";
```

Comment: I updated my answer, there are not big changes. But if it's a home work you should not use stack overflow to do this.

Comment: i'm really stuck in here, and i dont have any ideas to fix it haha, btw thanks for the answer. i will try it, if its not working i'll tell u thankss